# Failed to load mqe.dll using impersonation

Tags: c#, dll, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to a IBM MQ queue manager using local user created on the system.

I am using Win server 2008 R2, IBM MQ client and Server versions are 8.0.0.6

To run the code as a local user I have implemented impersonation. Now when I impersonate the user and try to connect I get below connection error.  When I run visual studio as a different user (local user), it works but not when I use impersonation.

Below is the trace:

```
 System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager' threw an exception.
  Source=amqmdnet
  TypeName=IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager
  StackTrace:
       at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..ctor(String queueManagerName, String Channel, String ConnName)
       at MQExample.MQTest.ConnectMQ(String strQueueManagerName, String strQueueName, String strChannelInfo) in D:\Adidas\MQExample\MQExample\MQExample\MQTest.cs:line 83
       at MQExample.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Adidas\MQExample\MQExample\MQExample\Form1.cs:line 33
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at MQExample.Program.Main() in D:\Adidas\MQExample\MQExample\MQExample\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146232828
       Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
            at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
            at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
            at IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.CreateCommonServices()
            at IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.TraceConstructor(String objectId, String sccsid)
            at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiEnvironment..ctor(NmqiPropertyHandler nmqiPropertyHandler)
            at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiFactory.GetInstance(NmqiPropertyHandler properties)
            at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..cctor()
       InnerException: 
            HResult=-2146232828
            Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
            Source=amqmdnet
            StackTrace:
                 at IBM.WMQ.MQCommonServices..ctor()
            InnerException: 
                 HResult=-2146233088
                 Message=Failed to load mqe.dll from folder C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\
                 Source=amqmdnet
                 StackTrace:
                      at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NativeManager.InitializeNativeApis(String mode)
                 InnerException:
```

code to implement it :

```
 using (new Tools.Impersonator("iibadmin", ".", "Test@1234"))
                    {
                        string userafter = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
                        MQQueueManager queueManager = null;
                        queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName, channelName, connectionName);

                        int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                        queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(QueueName, openOptions);
                        int depth = queue.CurrentDepth;
                        queueMessage = new MQMessage();
                        queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
                        queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                        queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);
                        strReturn =
                        queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);
                        queue.Close();

                        queueManager.Disconnect();
                    }
```

Comment: Does the file `C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\mqe.dll` exist?  Does the impersonated user have access to that file?  What is the reason you want to run it with impersonation?  Using impersonation in this manner would indicate the SVRCONN channel on the queue manager is not secure and is just accepting the userid that you impersonate on your server as valid.  With MQv8 you can send a username and password to the queue manager and if setup it will validate and use that ID to determine MQ access on the server, no impersonation required and security is better since you are authenticating.

Comment: Does the file `C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\mqe.dll` exist? Does the impersonated user have access to that file?

Comment: yes it does exist and Impersonated user has access  to it. When Visual studio is run as different user (local user which i was impersonating) , it works like butter. The same doesn't work when i impersonate it as run it. I am using MQ version 8.0.0.6 .  User in MQ server doesnot have password set , it has only Username. I couldnt set only username and  connect to the MQueueManager. i hope u mean setting userid property and password in hashtable property. Could you please let me know if it can be done with only username ?

Comment: As I said the fact that it works as the user you impersonate is a bad sign for security as it indicates the queue manager is just accepting the asserted user id.  Using the IBM MQ Classes for Java or JMS it is trivial to assert any id you want to.  With other APIs like .NET you need to run under a user of that name to assert the id, but if you have access to create a local users this is trivial as well.  Actually validating the ID and Password via `CONNAUTH` and using `ADOPTCTX(YES)` would mean you would now need the password as well to connect.

Comment: If you want to continue on with troubleshooting why impersonation does not exist I would suggest you enable a MQ trace on the server.  Another option is that based on the fact it is looking for `mqe.dll` it indicates it has been successful in calling `amqmdnet.dll` but is running in unmanaged mode meaning it requires other non-.NET dlls that come as part of the client install.  If you run it in managed mode it would not require any dlls except for `amqmdnet.dll`.

Comment: how do i run the code as managed code?

Comment: i have to connect to MQ server from  a client. Server MQ runs with a user "admin". how do i connect to sever from client with a specific user "admin" using .net? , i would be running the code with my local credentials. Is there a way to do this? I am using MQ server and client 8.0.0.6 , Win server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Your impersonated user probably does not have the MQ environment setup.

i.e. Environment variables:

```
PATH
LIB
MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH
MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH
MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH
MQ_JRE_PATH
```

If you are running 32-bit .NET then you need to point to the 32-bit MQ environment like wise for 64-bit.

i.e. mqe.dll is found in:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\mqe.dll
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin64\mqe.dll
```

Hence, it is a good idea to know what you are running and what MQ environment you need to setup.

Comment: if different bit (32 -64) bit was the issue , it shouldnt have connected when i run the VS as run as different user. I do have MQ client set up in my system.  How do i check the environment Variables  for the user?

Comment: Use the setmqenv command.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083560_.htm